# Laravel scout with ElasticSearch, how reset the index?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5.3

I'm working on a Laravel project and I'm using https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout with ElasticSearch on a model Offer.

With the command `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Offer"` I can generate an index for ElasticSearch with `offers` from my database, and it's ok. After that I can search `offers` in this index.

But now, I removed somes `offers` from my database, and I don't know how can I reset or re-generate the index for remove old ids ?

For example I removed `Offer with id = 15` in my database, but when I do a search, this offer (id=15) is always indexed, and I get an error because this offer doesn't exist.

I tried to re run the command `scout:import` but no effect. The only solution I fond is to rename the index with https://laravel.com/docs/master/scout#configuring-model-indexes but I can't do that each times...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `php artisan scout:flush "App\Models\Offer"`

You can also remove physical files for indexes from `storage` folder

Answer (score 0):

The driver should automatically remove/update the record when you do a remove/update on any Model declared as Searchable.

To flush the models use: php artisan scout:import Model

You could check the bugs area for laravel-scout, maybe there is something related or try an update to L5.4